# how to set focus to anchor tag which is inside a div element and the div element is having ng-show

Tags: angularjs, anchor, ng-show

```
<div   class="test" ng-show="model.data.IsDataLoaded" tabindex="50">
  <a href="" id="id1" ng-click="testData($event)">Clear all</a>
</div>
```

//in the js i am trying to set the focus by below code

```
$scope.model.data.IsDataLoaded = true;
 angular.element("#id1").focus();
```

Comment: If [Lex's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38137442/1218980) is not correct, you should comment on it for clarifications. If you found another answer, you should post it to mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ng-show` to `ng-if` and use a directive:

*js:*

```
.directive('autoFocus', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element[0].focus();
        }
    }
});
```

*html:*

```
<div class="test" ng-if="model.data.IsDataLoaded" tabindex="50">
    <a href="" id="id1" ng-click="testData($event)" auto-focus>Clear all</a>
</div>
```